# Firebase error when doing IAP

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

So this is the message I am receiving in swift

```
[Firebase/Analytics][*-*********] Purchase is a duplicate and will not be reported
```

I have multiple in app purchases for my one application and all of them appear this with message, showing each of their product ID's after the above message. I searched the internet and didn't find anything that would help me solve or get rid of these messages.

Anything would help! This is in swift 3, using Xcode!

Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Im having the same issue

Comment: Any fixes found?

Answer (score 0):

After adding Firebase Analytics to your iOS app the revenue of the iOS in-app purchases are automatically tracked in Firebase. However you need to link your Firebase app to itunes in order for those in-app purchases to be reported in Firebase Analytics. You can do so in the Firebase Project Settings->Account Linking section. So you need to get rid of firebase analytics part in case you not using it, for that manually use the pods that only necessary instead using the whole pod 'Firebase'.