# Purchase is a duplicate and will not be reported

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, revenuecat

I am using package [purchases_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/purchases_flutter) for handling in app purchase. This package is powered by [RevenueCat](https://www.revenuecat.com)

Payment dialog appear by executing this line

```
Purchases.purchasePackage(package);
```

For android all is working good but for iOS I am facing following error

```
Purchase is a duplicate and will not be reported. Product ID: product_id
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a Firebase Analytics message, not an error during the purchase process: [Firebase error when doing IAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44987610/firebase-error-when-doing-iap)

I believe it simply means Firebase Analytics think's it's already recorded an event for that purchase so it isn't logging again. This would be common during testing when you repeatedly buy the same product.

Comment: Is there any workaround for this issue? Because removing firebase analytics is not a good practice I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code in *AppDelegate.swift*

```
FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(.min)
```

Comment: I no longer get the message but now the IAP doesn't get triggered ....??